# How do you check if a tag is present on a page?

Tags: jekyll

Currently I'm doing this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
      {% for page in site.articles %}
         {% for tag in page.tags %}
            {% if tag == 'index' %}
              <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{page.title}}</a>
            {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    <ul>
</div>
```

Seems bad. I see some people online saying you can do this:

```
{% if page.tags[index] %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

...but this doesn't seem to work.

Is there some variation on this syntax that does actually work?

NB. `jekyll --version -> jekyll 2.5.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `site.articles` array, it's `site.pages` or `site.posts`.

You can do :

```
{% for p in site.pages %}
  {% if p.tags contains 'index' %}
     <li><a href="{{ p.url }}">{{p.title}}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Note** : do not use `page` variable in a loop because it is already used by the current page.

Comment: it's a collection, so yes there is, but thanks, contains is what I wanted.